# Disabled tabbing into url bar

Tags: javascript, html

I am using tabindex's to make a logical order in my form. At some point, when user passes beyond save button, we tabbs into the url bar. How can I disable that?

In other words: I want to make a kind of loop just on my elements.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to make a kind of loop just on your elements?

Comment: @Kermani, excatly.

Comment: So you want to cripple the user experience?

Comment: Haha, I want to limit his options

Comment: That *is* crippling the user experience. A user that is used to tabbing through a website expects that, eventually, the focus shifts from the website to the browser chrome. If you disable that, you make the user experience worse, not better.

Comment: This would explicitly break accessibility. http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/keyboard-operation-trapping.html

Comment: As other people are saying here, it is better to avoid do in it, even if you found a solution for it

Comment: Just imagine, your user has used to use tab and he/she supposed to press tab sometimes and get access to URL bar, this means you just destroyed your user experience :)  I hope he/she be polite enough and does not use bad words when you make him/her angry when she is pressing tab and can't access URL bar